# Groovy - class not found

Tags: mysql, jdbc, groovy, classnotfoundexception

The following Groovy script fails with a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` exception.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25')
])

import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance(
    'jdbc:mysql://localhost/books', 
    'root',
    '', 
    'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
);
```

I looked into the JAR file stored at `C:\Users\Dusan\.groovy\grapes\mysql\mysql-connector-java\jars\mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar` and it contains the Driver class.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
```

After your @Grab, and just:

```
@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance(
    'jdbc:mysql://localhost/books', 
    'root',
    '', 
    'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
)
```

Should do

Answer (score 1):

How do you use it in groovysh ?

As per the doc, Grab is used in the shell this way

```
groovy.grape.Grape.grab([group:'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25'])
```

I haven't found the equivalent for @GrabConfig.  It simply does not work inside groovysh.

Comment: Did you found any solution yet ?