# Grails + MySQL: No suitable driver found

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I'm running grails 2.4.0 and I'm trying to access a MySQL database using groovy.sql.  I know this question pops up in search, but those solutions don't work.  I keep getting...

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://...
```

- I've checked and double checked the url, and it is formatted correctly.
- I've dropped mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar in my project lib
- I've also uncommented "runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'" in the dependencies block of BuildConfig (not in conjunction with the lib jar)

The error never changes.  What am I doing wrong here?

For example, I have a service class with a method that I'd like to connect to a MySQL database and pull data without using the Grails datasource mechanism.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class TestService {

def doStuff() {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db', 'username', 'password', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
    sql.eachRow("select * from some_table") {...
```

Comment: You said "I'm trying to access a MySQL database using groovy.sql".  What does "using groovy.sql" mean?  The solution to your problem may depend on that.

Comment: I edited the question with a sample of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to uncomment but comment it out and no need to tell for the grails you have mysql dependencies , if u have added it on your Lib folder.
and Make sure u have may be non bogus driver jar. i have used the following :

> dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
>
> mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar

Ok if those work.

Have u tried ur connection string declaration this way and also try to use datasource as below

```
def db = [url:'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?autoreconnect=true', user:'root',
         password:'',driver:'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']

def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
```

To test if driver problem or missconfiguration test it with the actual datasource settings as follow assuming ur datasource has

```
dataSource {
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "root"
    password = "root"
}
```

this can also be achived by passing

> `datasource` to `Sql.newInstance(datasource)`

And also try this as aletrnative :

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import javax.sql.DataSource
import groovy.sql.Sq

driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver // can be ommited

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    'url:'jdbc:mysql://<server>/<database>?user=<username>&password=<password>');

Sql sql = new Sql(conn);
```

And also try this one

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
```

After your @Grab, and just:

```
@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance(
    'jdbc:mysql://localhost/books', 
    'root',
    '', 
    'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
)
```

If none works bring the mysql jar file under this groovy class , this may be dumb but there must be no reason not to work ... Cheers!!

[Reference 1 :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036110/groovy-class-not-found)
&&
[Reference 2 :](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features)

Comment: So adding it as a datasource with dialect works, but It's not what I'm trying to do.  I will eventually want my datasource to be a pgsql database, but I'll need to occasionally pull from a legacy mysql db.  That legacy db is what I want to use groovy.sql.Sql for.

Comment: The dialect will be of no consequence when you are using groovy.sql.Sql.  The dialect is only relevant when you are using Hibernate.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - I'm aware of that, but for whatever reason, the problem persists unless I set up the connection as a datasource in Datasource.groovy.  For now it works because I don't need a traditional grails datasource as I'm just setting up non-db services for now.  That will change in the future, so I'm still looking for a long-term solution.

Comment: That does not make sense to me.  You are using groovy.sql.Sql and there is no mention of GORM anywhere in the question so I don't see anything that suggests that DataSource.groovy needs to be involved at all, and certainly nothing that suggests that a Hibernate dialect should be relevant.  It shouldn't.  I don't know why you are defining the thing in DataSource.groovy at all.

Comment: The answer here talks about the hibernate plugin and the Hibernate dialect.  None of that has anything to do with the question as written.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Everything you're saying is correct.  I don't want to use Datasource.groovy for this as I can't long term, and it's overkill for what I'm trying to do.  BUT, if I set up the db connection in Datasource.groovy, I can successfully connect to the db in question using groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(dataSource).  To date, that's the only way I've been able to connect.

Comment: I have to say that your original post is the only thing that has led me to a working solution.  I ended up just setting this database up as a second datasource with dbCreate to "validate" and it's working enough. 

Grails just seems to not want to allow me to set the driver while initializing the Sql object.  Oh well.